# Adding an array of buttons to a Flow Pane

Tags: arrays, javafx

I need to add an array of 20 buttons to a flow pane. I have the array created but can't seem to get all of the buttons show up. Why is it only adding one button?

```
public class Activity4 extends Application 
{
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{
    Button[] btn = new Button[20];
    for(int i=0; i<btn.length;i++)
    {
        btn[i] = new Button();
        btn[i].setText("Safe!");
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn[i]);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Button Blast!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
        btn[i].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Hello World!");
                }
        });     
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every iteration of the loop, you are creating a new `FlowPane`, and then creating a new `Scene` and setting it to the stage.

You need to create one `FlowPane` *before* the loop. In the loop, create the buttons, register the handler with them, and add them to the flow pane.

The *after* the loop, create the `Scene` with the flow pane, set it in the stage, and show the stage.

Comment: @j.doe This error was hidden because of bad formatting. Make use of autoformat in whatever IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
public class Activity4 extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        Button [] btn = new Button[20];
        for(int i=0; i<btn.length;i++)
        {
            btn[i] = new Button();
            btn[i].setText("Safe!");

        }
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Button Blast!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

[image]